# How to install a python shared library in rust project in windows?

Tags: python, rust, shared-libraries, rust-crates

[crate link for reference](https://crates.io/crates/pyo3#:%7E:text=To%20install%20the%20Python%20shared%20library%20on%20Ubuntu%3A)
Here they gave a command to install a python package in rust but in ubuntu only...
I saw about shared libraries but idk what library to install
`` error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\pytest.exe` (exit code: 0xc0000135, STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND) `` this is the error code now how do i get pytest.exe i dont understand thatand btw cargo project name is pytest but i dont understand how to get this

Comment: It's unclear. You need to provide a [mre] and debugging details. Did you install Python and ensure it's in the PATH? I recommend the Rust platform, x86_64-pc-windows-msvc, because the official Windows Python package is built with MSVC.